# Erasing String that contains null

Tags: java, regex, string, null, replaceall

I have a null value in my message or println that i want to delete, all succeed when i just using code like this.

the message before :

```
message = 2014-06-02 14:53:37.103 null tes
```

Here is the code that delete the null word.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    //final int month = Integer.parseInt(period[0]),  year = Integer.parseInt(period[1]);
    Date x = new Date();
    Timestamp t = new Timestamp(x.getTime());
    String a = "null";
    String b = t+" " +a + " tes";

    String tes = (b.trim()!= null && b.trim().length()>=23) ? b.trim().replaceFirst(b.trim().substring(0,28), ""+t) : b;

    System.out.println("message = " + tes);

}
```

The printout is right. its like this :

```
message = 2014-06-02 14:53:37.103 tes
```

But when i insert this `|` the printout gone wrong. i'm using that as a separator. 
This is the code that went wrong.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    //final int month = Integer.parseInt(period[0]),  year = Integer.parseInt(period[1]);
    Date x = new Date();
    Timestamp t = new Timestamp(x.getTime());
    String a = "null";
    String b = t+"| " +a + " tes";

    String tes = (b.trim()!= null && b.trim().length()>=23) ? b.trim().replaceFirst(b.trim().substring(0,28), ""+t) : b;

    System.out.println("message = " + tes);

}
```

And this is the print out :

```
message = 2014-06-02 14:58:03.148| null tes
```

What happen to the second code actually?
Thanks

Comment: Side note: `b.trim()!= null` will never help you. If `b` is null, you'll get a NPE calling `trim()`. If `b` is not null, then `trim()` will return an empty string at worst.

Comment: Why not split on space and take the first two elements? `replaceFirst` relies on regex - read the [JavaDoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replaceFirst(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String)). Pipe has a special meaning in regex.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to simply strip out the 'null' text string without the regEx issues above, and quickly and cleanly, just replace the 'null' String directly.

```
b.replace("null", "")
```

Comment: nice and quite simple. why i cant think about it. lol. thanks bro.

Answer (score 2):

As Boris said there are other ways, but the main problem is that `replaceFirst` takes a regex and pipe is a special character in regex.

Below with the introduction of [`Pattern.quote`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html#quote%28java.lang.String%29) the code should work:

```
b.trim().replaceFirst(Pattern.quote(b.trim().substring(0,28)), ""+t)
```

Answer (score 0):

What is exactly the main purpose of the program? if it is just to remove the null in the String, I would do as JamasA says. Otherwise if you want to get the timestamp and the "tes" string in two clean strings I would do it in this way:

```
String tes = b.replace("null", "");
String[] aux = tes.split("\\|");
for (int i = 0; i < aux.length; i++) {
    System.out.println(aux[i].trim());
}
```

In this way you get both information separated.I hope it will helpful for you :)